# what is .d file after building with make

Tags: linux, build, makefile

Sometimes, I find `.d` files for a given source file.
For instance, if I compile `test.c`, I've got

```
test.d, test.o
```

I understand that `test.o` is the object file but have no idea what is `test.d` for.
Could you give any hints or pointers?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Many build systems add automatically detected `make` dependencies into the `.d` file.  In particular, for C/C++ source files they determine what `#include` files are required and automatically generate that information into the `.d` file.

The `.d` files are then included by the `makefile` so `make` is aware of that information.  If you look at the contents of those files they'll be make prerequisite statements, like:

```
foo.o : foo.h bar.h biz.h
```

etc.

Comment: Is there a better way to calculate and define the dependencies than to clutter your directory with .d files?

Comment: Many people configure their makefiles to write the `.d` files into a subdirectory so they don't clutter the current directory.

Comment: That would be a very useful thing for me.How can I do that?

Comment: The comments of a SO question are not the place to discuss it.  It's not hard: basically wherever your current makefile writes to `$*.d` you write to `.deps/$*.d` or whatever instead.  If you can't figure it out you can ask a new question, showing your current makefile content that generates dependencies then someone can help you modify it to write to a subdirectory.  Also you can read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: How do you use the .d files in a recipe to generate objects?

Comment: Look for -MMD in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

the `.d` files contain rules and can be added to Makefile's existing rules.

Makefile fragment:

```
clean:
        rm -v *.o *.d

DEPS := $(wildcard *.d)
ifneq ($(DEPS),)
include $(DEPS)
endif
```