# How can I view source code from a .i file?

Tags: c++

I got the source code for a project,but it's full of .i and .d files. When I use windows notepad or sublime text to open them trying to view their source code, they are all messy codes.So the question is like the title above.Anyone could help?

Comment: I don't think any tools exist to do this. But compilers tend to add comment markers between files so maybe you can write a small script to split it up.

Comment: Who gave these files to you? Where did you download them from? That would give some clues about what format they're in. They may not be source code at all but some kind of IDE metadata.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137743/where-do-we-use-i-files-and-how-do-we-generate-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137743/where-do-we-use-i-files-and-how-do-we-generate-them)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114410/what-is-d-file-after-building-with-make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114410/what-is-d-file-after-building-with-make)

Comment: As a result neither of these are meant for reading or editing. They are intermediate files in the build process.

Comment: You can try to open in visual studio IDE, you will able to find if those are the binary or text files. it can open binary as well, just try it if you are in windows.

Comment: I believe these are gcc intermediate build files not useful at all for Visual Studio.